# AngularJS $http undefined

Tags: http, angularjs, module

I get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined` when running this module:

```
angular.module('EventList', [])

.config([ '$routeProvider', function config($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when(Urls.EVENT_LIST_PAGE, {
        templateUrl: 'app/EventList/event-list.html',
        controller: 'EventListCtrl'
      });
 }])


.controller('EventListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function EventListController($scope, $location, $http) {
  $scope.events = [];
  $http.get('http://localhost:8000/event').
    success(function (data, status) {
      $scope.events = data;
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        $scope.events[i].event_url = ('#' + Urls.EVENT_PAGE + '/' + $scope.events[i]._id);
      }
    }).
    error(function (data, status) {
      $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
    }
  );

}]);
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using the bracket notation the dependency list before the function needs to match the services being injected into the function.

You have an extra `$location` service in your `EventsListController` function so change this:

```
.controller('EventListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function EventListController($scope, $location, $http) {
// controller code goes here
}]);
```

to this:

```
.controller('EventListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function EventListController($scope, $http) {
// controller code goes here
}]);
```

The key change being: `function EventListController($scope, $http)` instead of `function EventListController($scope, $location, $http)`

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer twice!  This wasn't my exact cause, but helped.  My editor failed to update my .min file, which is only used in production, so I spent quite a while trying to figure out why my deployment broke production and no other environment.  Thanks for saving my weekend!